# Solve $yx^2-zx+v=0$ for x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having trouble solving $yx^2-zx+v=0$. $y$,$z$, and $v$ are constants. I cannot just plug into the quadratic formula whilst solving this. I'll post what I have done even though I do not think I am on the right track. $$yx^2-zx+v=0\rightarrow yx^2-zx=-v\rightarrow x(yx -z)=-v$$
$$x=\frac{-v}{yx-z}\rightarrow x=\frac{-v}{yx-z}\left( \frac{yx+z}{yx+z}\right)\rightarrow$$
$$x=\frac{-v(yx+z)}{(yx)^2-z^2}\rightarrow x((yx)^2-z^2)=-v(yx+z)$$
$$y^2x^3-xz^2=-yvx-vz\rightarrow y^2x^3-xz^2+yvx=-vz $$
$$\frac{y^2x^3-xz^2+yvx}{-vz}=1 \rightarrow$$
$$\frac{y^2x^3}{-vz}+\frac{xz}{v}-\frac{yx}{z}=1$$
Multiply both sides by
$vz$ and I end with $$-y^2x^3+xz^2-yxv=vz$$but I feel I am not going anywhere. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: use quadratic formula or complete the square http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula

Comment: This is a quadratic equation in $x$. So, why can't you use the quadratic formula?

Comment: @user172209 i'll try completing the square but I cannot use the quadratic formula as I specified.

Comment: "Completing the square" *is* the quadratic formula...

Comment: @User58220 thanks, I'm not too familiar so sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: You could look here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using complete the square:

$$yx^2-zx+v=0$$

$$y(x^2-\frac{z}{y})+v=0$$

$$y((x-\frac{z}{2y})^2-\frac{z^2}{4y^2})+v=0$$

$$y(x-\frac{z}{2y})^2-\frac{z^2}{4y}+v=0$$

From here you can easily solve for $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Wasn't aware of "completing the square".

Comment: Well, if you take $ax^2+bx+c=0$, perform the same process, and simplify, you will end up with the quadratic formula! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: Quadratic formula for $ax^2+bx+c=0$ gives that 
$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$

So, if we have $yx^2 −zx+v=0$, can you see what $a,b,c$ should be?

Completing the square:
\begin{align*}
ax^2+bx+c&=0\\
x^2+\frac{b}{a}x&=-\frac{c}{a}\\
x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}&=-\frac{c}{a}+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\\
\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2&=-\frac{c}{a}+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\\
x+\frac{b}{2a}&=\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: The instructions say I cannot use the quadratic formula..

Comment: @Kenshin But whatever you do, you won't get a different result. (Except that you should be careful if $y$ might me zero)

Comment: I must show the whole algebraic process whenever turning in the answer. Otherwise trust me, I would've done the quadratic formula haha.

Comment: @Kenshin I've updated the answer, but I guess it's too late now. :(

Comment: It'd be unfair to change the correct answer, but thanks anyways!

Comment: @Kenshin Of course it is! It's my fault I misread your question.